# Moodle plugin : check if admin + add link to plugin in administration

Tags: php, moodle

I'm new to moodle plugin development and am trying to create a plugin that displays a page to the admin where I can add my on php code.

In brief, what I want the plugin to do I have already achieved in a standard php file that I upload to the moodle root. From here you can call the file e.g. yourdomain.co.uk/moodlelocation/myfile.php and it will run as expected.

The problem with this is it isn't secure since anyone can load the myfile.php and in turn run the scripts on the page. It also means any one else using this script (it will be given away for free when complete) would need to FTP into their hosting and upload two php files to their moodle install.

Due to this, I thought a plugin (a very very basic plugin) may be the best solution. They could then load the page in the admin via the "site administration". e.g. site administration > Development > MyPlugin. I am assuming I could then also restrict the plugin's main page to admins only (??).

So to recap, I can create a php page that has my script all rocking and rolling BUT I need to make this into a plugin.

I did some reading and I think a "local" plugin was the easiest way to go (??).

I have managed to get the local plugin up and running using the below in local/webguides/inex.php :

```
<?php

// Standard config file and local library.

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../config.php');

// Setting up the page.

$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());

$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');

$PAGE->set_title("webguides");

$PAGE->set_heading("webguides");

$PAGE->set_url(new moodle_url('/local/webguides/index.php'));

// Ouput the page header.

echo $OUTPUT->header();

echo 'MY php CODE here etc';

?>
```

This works fine but with two problems:

1. Anyone can access it via http://domain/local/webguides/index.php
2. There is no link to it in the site administration (so the user would need to type the URL in).

Can anyone shed any light how I would achieve the two steps above?

Thanks in advance

p.s. ideally I'd like to keep the plugin to as few files as possible so if the required code could be added to the local/webguides/index.php file it would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a capability, then require that capability before displaying the page.

First, have a look at `local/readme.txt` - this gives an overview of the files needed for a local plugin.

Or read the documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins

Also have a look at existing local plugins so you can see how they are created - https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=type:local

At a bare minimum, you need

```
local/webguides/db/access.php - this will have the capability
local/webguides/lang/en/local_webguides.php
local/webguides/version.php
```

Plus your index file

```
local/webguides/index.php
```

In the `db/access.php` file have something like

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$capabilities = array(

    'local/webguides:view' => array(
        'captype' => 'read',
        'contextlevel' => CONTEXT_SYSTEM,
        'archetypes' => array(
        ),
    ),

);
```

You might also need `'riskbitmask' => RISK_XXX` depending on if there are any risks in you code. Such as `RISK_CONFIG`, `RISK_PERSONAL`, etc.

In `lang/en/local_webguides.php` have something like

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$string['pluginname'] = 'Webguides';
$string['webguides:view'] = 'Able to view webguids';
```

In `version.php` have something like

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version   = 2020051901;        // The current plugin version (Date: YYYYMMDDXX)
$plugin->requires  = 2015051109;        // Requires this Moodle version.
$plugin->component = 'local_webguides'; // Full name of the plugin (used for diagnostics).
```

Replace `2015051109` with the version of Moodle you are using - this will be in `version.php` in the root folder.

Then in your `index.php` file use this near the top.

```
require_capability('local/webguides:view', context_system::instance());
```

So only users with that capability will have access to the page.

EDIT:

You can add a link via `settings.php` using something like

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

if ($hassiteconfig) {
    $page = new admin_externalpage(
        'local_webguides',
        get_string('pluginname', 'local_webguides'),
        new moodle_url('/local/webguides/index.php'),
        'local/webguides:view'
    );

    $ADMIN->add('localplugins', $page);
}
```

Then in your index page ad this

```
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/adminlib.php');
```

and remove `require_login()` and `require_capability()` and replace with

```
admin_externalpage_setup('local_webguides');
```

Comment: wow, thank you very much, I will be working on this again tomorrow morning so will give the above a try. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi, I created the above (thanks again) and have installed it via the moodle plugin section, installed great but I am unable to see any link in the admin to the "site administration".  Should the above cause it to show up?

Comment: partially acheived this using :
<?php
// Add the settings page to the navigation block
$settings = new admin_settingpage(
    'local_webguides', 
    get_string('pluginname', 'local_webguides')
);
$ADMIN->add('localplugins', $settings);
?>
but now I'm stuck on how to add custom code to the settings page

Comment: Hey, I've updated the answer to add a link to the site admin menu